# PlayFramework routes StackOverflowError

Tags: java, playframework, stack-overflow

I'm using the Play framework 2.2.1.

When I compile the project, I got a `StackOverflowError`. I check my route file and I found that some routes that used assets to files cause the problem.

```
GET /Admin/*file controllers.Assets.at(path="/public/Admin",file)
GET /Pic/*file controllers.Assets.at(path="/public/Pic",file)
```

And some more routes like them.

What are the common reasons to such errors? Do I need to minimize my routs file to the minimum required?

Comment: This routes are normal. We'll need more data to answer your question. Edit your question and post the whole routes file.

Comment: And please post the Stacktrace.